# CakePhp 2.3.5 - kcaptcha plugin, install and get an error Kcaptcha.CaptchaComponent could not be found?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Follow this topic https://github.com/hiromi2424/CakePHP-Kcaptcha-Plugin, I copy the folder I downloaded, paste it into plugin folder and change name it's Kcaptcha. And then, add this code `CakePlugin::load('Kcaptcha', array('bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => false))` to bootstrap file. After that, I add some code in UsersController `var $components = array('Kcaptcha.Captcha');`. I get an error Missing Component

**Error: Kcaptcha.CaptchaComponent could not be found.
Error: Create the class CaptchaComponent below in file: C:\xampp\htdocs\zik\app\Plugin\Kcaptcha\Controller\Component\CaptchaComponent.php**

I don't know why, have you any idea?

Comment: Are you using the correct Kcaptcha version? You've linked to the master branch, which is the CakePHP 1.3.x version of the component. With CakePHP 2.x you'll need the version from the [2.0 branch](https://github.com/hiromi2424/CakePHP-Kcaptcha-Plugin/tree/2.0). And if you are using the 2.0 branch, have you checked whether the file mentioned in the error message actually exists?

Comment: I'm using CakePhp 2.3.5. I see on Kcaptcha home page, they say it can be used with CakePhp 1.3, 2.0, 2.1. Do you think it can't be used with CakePhp 2.3.5?

Comment: You've mentioned your CakePHP Version in the title, I'm talking about the Kcaptcha version, there are two, and only the 2.0 branch is compatible with CakePHP 2.

Comment: I think it's 2.0 and I download it from https://github.com/hiromi2424/CakePHP-Kcaptcha-Plugin

Comment: Again, you've linked to the master branch, which is the Kcaptcha version for CakePHP 1.3.x. Just look in the downloaded `README.md` and check the `Requirements` section. The 2.0 branch is the one I've linked in my first comment: https://github.com/hiromi2424/CakePHP-Kcaptcha-Plugin/tree/2.0

Comment: Oh, I really sorry. Thanks for you help.